Receiving mail from pop server with mutt
I want to write a script to receive mails from a POP server and write them to file using mutt command.
I use this secuence.
mutt -e "push \nC\n\ndq\n" -f 'pops://user:password@my_mail_server'
With this options:
enter the mutt console
copy message to file
delete mail
quit
Then I can work with the mail in the file, searching for patterns, removing unwanted text, etc.
The problem is when there are no new messages in the mailbox for this user, then the sequence above doesn't work and enters to the console but doesn't quit automatically. I need a command before to check if there are new messages in the mailbox, and if not, doing nothing.
Is could be a non interactive sequence similar to check or count if there is a new message and return this value to a script?
I hope I have explained it correctly.
Regards
